# clicking on iphone mobile arrow key when reach to the dropdown list, it should display the dropdown list contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, iphone

I want to open/show the dropdown list contents (just like when clicked on a dropdown) when the arrow keys in iphone mobile keyboard near to the AutoFill are tapped.

I am doing this for my web app in safari browser. I have written the FOCUS event for the dropdown but it is not woring. I am using bootstrap split button dropdowns.

```
<!-- Split button -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Action</button>
  <button type="button" class="inFocusedDropdown btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The focus event is:

```
var clickOnce = 0;
    $(".inFocusedDropdown").focus(function(event){
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        clickOnce += 1;
        if(clickOnce == 1){
            $(this).trigger("click");
        }
        clickOnce = 0;
    });
```

The image below shows the arrow keys from iphone 6 mobile; when tap on an arrow key and a dropdown reaches, it should display the dropdown contents but it not Working.

[IMAGE -- iphone keyboard arrow keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oI6eG.png)

Hope to hear from you all, soon. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **is** possible! Check this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/830vozou/)

Give your dropdown an id like `dropdown1`

Insert this input somewhere near to your dropdown:

```
<input class="focus-trigger" triggerid="dropdown1" />
```

Hide input with css:

```
.focus-trigger {
  width:0;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Add JavaScript:

```
$(".focus-trigger").focus(function(e){
  $("#"+$(this).attr("triggerid")).trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: Yes. thank you. It is a nice hack to get what is intended.